# How to compare two values without if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I compare two values **without if/else statement**?

e.g

`var One = $('#one').height();`
`var Two = $('#two').height();`

How to check which value is higher **without if/else statement**?

There is no must to avoid `if/else` statament - **exercises only.**

Comment: Without if/else statement? Interesting requirement. You have some problems with if/else?

Comment: This is silly. State an actual practical requirement please.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - exercises only.

Comment: @NewUser: And what does that mean?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - looking for alternative ways of doing stuff. To make code: shorter, more efficient etc.. E.G. `var greatest = Math.max(One, Two);` is 1 one line in place of 4.

Comment: @NewUser: So by "exercises only", the full sentence you are looking for is "just out of interest; I am looking for ways to condense my coding style".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - in general - yes. Not condense - improve be the word. But in many case, shorter code is improved code. Coding skills improvement by looking for (better)alternative ways of doing stuff (coding/programing).

Comment: @NewUser: Be warned: this is a slippery slope. You do not know what is "better" until you have an actual problem to solve; one approach may be appropriate in some scenarios but not in others.

Comment: And as an example: a call to Math.max might be slower than an inline if/else. Less text in the code doesn't always mean faster and/or more readable.

Comment: @Hans - you may be right here. Did not come out shorter eighter! :) http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/wDqfh/17/

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - I may have over-do-it - did not came out shorter; and does not work properly! :) http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/wDqfh/17/

Comment: @NewUser If you're only interested in the *numerical difference* between two numbers, use `Math.abs()`: `var difference = Math.abs(number1 - number2);`.

Comment: I have no idea at all what your goal is there.

Comment: Seems to work for me; the `.simpleList` expands to the bottom of its container. jensgram is right, though; you can do this far more succinctly.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - same height divs.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal - the values are correct - there was CSS padding issue.

Comment: You're not good at writing full sentences, are you?! :(

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - sorry, which one is not clear?

Comment: "same height divs" - I got it about as much as I need to, but it's a bit frustrating sometimes! Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal  - thanks! The goal is to write a plug-in, which will compare divs heights - to make sure they are the same height (keep make layout ease on eye).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to write if/else you could use the `? :` operator to get the higher value:

```
var higher = (One > Two) ? One : Two;
```

Comment: Is it just an if/else shorthand?

Comment: @NewUser, yes, it's the ternary operator.

Comment: [pedant mode] it's the *conditional operator* that is the only example of "a" ternary operator. (ternary means three operands, as compared to binary that takes two)[/pedant mode]

Answer (score 8):

you can use Math.max([..])

```
var higherValue = Math.max($('#one').height(), $('#two').height());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in **the greatest value**:

```
var greatest = Math.max(One, Two);
```

If you need to **set a boolean flag**:

```
var oneIsHighest = One > Two;
```

Answer (score 0):

A [ternary statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

```
(One > Two) ? /* do stuff if true */ : /* do other stuff if false */;
```

It should be noted that this is just a compact `if/else` statement, often referred to as an inline `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let one=100,two=50
one>two ? 1:0;
```

if conditions are correct 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let num1 = 2,num2  = 4;

num1<num2 && console.log('num2 is greater');

num1>num2 && console.log('num1 is greater);
```

**Explanation**:
In And operator
When first operand is true then only it will move to the another operand.

****first operand is num1<num2 it is true so,**

**second operand is console.log('num2 is greater');****

**Output will be** "num2 is greater" because 1st operand is true and move to second operand which will log in console "num2 is greater"

Comment: Please edit this answers formatting, as it is currently very unclear.